# cp the only files when permission is granted in the a directory

Tags: cp, mv

I would like to cp the whole directory, however inside that directory, it has some files which I don't permission to cp over. Is there any flag I can use in this case. Or are there any other command I should consider ? I think there should be a smart way to do this, like combine other commands Any help is appreciated.

For example,

```
text1.txt text2.txt *text3 text4.txt* text5.txt
```

text3 is another directory, and text4 is a file. While both of them, I don't have permission to access or view for now.

but the rest of files (or directory) I have the permission to cp over. 
How can we cp the only files with permission?

Comment: Just ignore all the errors is fine

Comment: @daisy  , Thank you.  It works for the problem i try to solve.

Answer (score 1):

This seems simple, unless you're not providing all the information about what you're trying to achieve.  Simply do

```
cp -r text* SOMEOTHERLOCATION
```

If you wanted to make it more complex, or if it's necessary (for some reason), you could do

```
find /some/directory/ -name '*text*' -user myusername -exec cp {} /some/other/directory/ \;
```

Comment: . Thank you. but I think your overkilled it. something to learn.